# Maytag Model- La612 Series 04 fills up on it's on and then starts running by it's self

Tags: washer

My friend has an old Maytag washer and the other night it filled up on its in and just turned on and started running scaring her half to death. I am thinking the water inlet valve, but I can't understand why the washer is running on its on if it is switched off. Any ideas??

Answer (score -1):

If its running (agitating, changing gears, etc) its not the water valve, its the master control switch.  Its getting a ghost signal to begin the wash process, or its just faulty.  I would suspect the latter.